# How to make a canvas resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

i draw a canvas with a image and i want when browser resize, this image can responsive with browser. This is my code

```js
function draw_canvas() {
  var img = new Image();
  var canvas = $('canvas')[0];
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.onload = function(){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, $('#canvas_panel').width(), $('#canvas_panel').height());
  };
  img.src = 'http://dicprj.moe/media/mathimages/en/arithmetic_kinder_counting_money_01_10.png';

}
$(document).ready(function() {
  draw_canvas();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
     $('#canvas_panel > canvas').each(function(i,v) {
  if($(this).height() != $('#canvas_panel').height() || 
     $(this).width() !=   $('#canvas_panel').width()) 
  {
    $(this).attr({
      'height' : $('#canvas_panel').height() + 'px',
      'width'  : $('#canvas_panel').width() + 'px'  
    });
  }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DRAWING</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="canvas_panel" style="height: 500px; widht: 800px" >
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

- The problem : when browser resize i can't can see canvas, canvas changed px but it empty. can you help me ?
- im trying with code :

```js
if($(this).height() != $('#canvas_panel').height() || $(this).width() != $('#canvas_panel').width()) {
    
  $(this).attr({
    'height' : $('#canvas_panel').height(),
    'width'  : $('#canvas_panel').width()  
  });
  //draw_canvas();
  var ctx = $(this)[0].getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage($(this)[0].toDataURL(), 0, 0, $('#canvas_panel').width(),     $('#canvas_panel').height());
  var img  = new Image();
  var canvas  = $(this)[0];
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.onload = function(){
    var canvas = cloneCanvas();
    var ctx = .getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, $('#canvas_panel').width(), $('#canvas_panel').height());
  };
  img.src = $(this)[0].toDataURL();
}
```

Thank

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you resize a canvas, you need to redraw it. So, call the `draw_canvas();` function after resizing. The new code would become

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('#canvas_panel > canvas').each(function(i,v) {
    if($(this).height() != $('#canvas_panel').height() || 
      $(this).width() !=   $('#canvas_panel').width()) 
    {
      $(this).attr({
        'height' : $('#canvas_panel').height() + 'px',
        'width'  : $('#canvas_panel').width() + 'px'    
      });
      draw_canvas();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: the content of draw_canvas function ?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Well, you could just call the `draw_canvas();` function, instead of writing new code.

Comment: I have it working (with a different image) on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6a22tnam/)

Comment: thank you, but when resize width/height of browser, with/height of canvas still 800px/500px, it's not responesive. 
Can you help me? canvas can change size with browser ?

Comment: Thank you so much, but it's still resolve my problem .

Comment: @OMGTran. Please don't say "I resolved my problem" without posting your solution as an answer. Failing to show your answer just clutters Stackoverflow with unanswered dead-ends. If Daan Meijer's answer helped you find your solution it would be kind to upvote his answer in addition to posting your self-answer.

Comment: OK, Thank you, i'm sorry .

Answer (score 0):

The css can resolve this problem, just set width/height css to canvas :

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```